# How to build APK file with html, css and js file which will run on any android phone

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

i have no idea how to develop mobile apps which would run on android phone. just browsing good and found a url where i saw they apps can convert my html file to apk file. here is the url [HTML-to-APK](https://github.com/praveshagrawal/HTML-to-APK)

i like to develop a tiny apps which will direct open camera and when user take any photo then picture will be shown in my html image control.

i got a another url http://www.ripperdesignandmultimedia.com/2012/09/06/jquery-mobile-use-phone-camera-using-cordova-2-0/

they show how to do it. they are saying i need to work with `Cordova js`

```
what is Cordova ?
```

is it any library or framework ?

so tell me if i develop the code following the above url then convert that html file to apk with a another apps then tell me does my apk will work?

guide me how to build my apk as a result all runtime environment should be installed in android phone to run my apps successfully. `i know .Net technology, html, jquery and javascript. what else i need to know.`

thanks

Comment: check this out ... https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/#supported_platforms_section check this. you can create different files for crossplatform devices.

Comment: http://phonegap.com/ would be another option to start with.

Comment: I recommend you Intel XDK, it's a IDE for HTML5 apps for Android, iOS and Windows Phone. It's free and Cordova is already included - it will do the work for you.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk

Comment: what is cordova and phonegap and how both are different. asking this because honestly i have no idea about this technology.

Comment: recommend me something which is free and which can be developed from Visual studio IDE.

Comment: @Thomas https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/explore/cordova-vs you would like to see this.

Answer (score 5):

[Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) is hybrid mobile application framework
You can build mobile application using HTML, CSS, Javascript

To create mobile application using cordova install it in your machine

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Make sure you need [Node js](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed in your machine to install cordova.

After cordova install create project and add platform

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd  hello
cordova platform add android
```

You can find hello folder in directory where you are running this command
Go to hello>www directory
put your html css and javascript code there and connect device and run command

```
cordova run android
```

You can see application installed in your device

Comment: why u said "Cordovais hybrid mobile application framework" ?

Comment: This is hybrid framework because you really don't need to know java to create android application and don't need to learn objective c or swift to develop iOS application. if you are familier  with HTML, CSS, JS then you can create application using this framework

Comment: Actually they are showing html in web view so its looks like application

Comment: what is phonegap ? what is relation between phonegap and cordova or both is totally different?

Comment: I had to install Android Studio and link JAVA_HOME path for cordova to work, but overall your answer is good and helpful.